# neo4j how to create node/graph now using int array

Tags: neo4j

I'm try to create the neo4j node in eclipse using following code. 
i try to import the large data file which the connection and node are just simple number.

```
int[] newnode=new int[10];
for(int i=0; i<newnode.length; i++){
     Node newnode[i]=db.createNode();
}

newnode[1].createRelationshipTo(newnode[2], Rels.KNOWS );
```

while this don't work. i am trying to test.
my data file for connection is like

```
1 3
4 5
```

Comment: If you are just wanting to import data into Neo4j, there are other perhaps better ways to do so. Take a look at https://github.com/jexp/batch-import

Comment: i want to create a data graph using existing data text file.

Comment: If you can convert it to a CSV file then I recommend using the batch import utility that I linked.

Answer (score 0):

use Node[] will be fine.
neo4j has Node[] to do this.